# Why is a comma the only special-character implode delimiter that works for me in this query?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, explode, implode

I've consistently noticed that when I try to use an array in a MySQL query that is within an Ajax Call (at least, I've only tried it from within an Ajax call) on a special-character-delimiter-separated string, my query only works if the character is a comma. For example, this works:

```
$myString = "String1,String2,String3,String4";
$ExplodedString =  explode(",", $myString);
$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT user FROM login WHERE column IN ('".implode("','", $ExplodedString)."') ORDER BY user");
```

But I can never get another special character, even the underscore, to return ANYTHING:

```
$myString = "String1_String2_String3_String4";
$ExplodedString =  explode("_", $myString);
$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT user FROM login WHERE column IN ('".implode("'_'", $ExplodedString)."') ORDER BY user");

//There are no error messages in my error log, even though error reporting is ON
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: because a comma not an underscore is a sperator in mysql IN

Comment: "empty query, but no error in my PHP error_log" if you checked for mysql errors you would get one

Comment: @Dagon...my mistake....I did get a warning: PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in etc....will update my post

Comment: -2....what the heck?

Comment: Why is this a -2? I corrected my error message comment

Comment: the implode failing error and the mysql issue are separate. which code produces what exact php error ?

Comment: delimiters used in initial string are completely irrelevant to the implode. You are imploding an array regardless of how it was created

Comment: @charlietfl...Look, underscore didn't work, and see Dagon's comment that only a comma should be used

Comment: Anyone want to take away a downvote...nothing wrong with my post at all

Comment: Downvotes are for questions which "do not show any research effort". Since the first step to debugging this for most people would be to manually log into the DBMS and run the same query as the application is running, and there's no evidence that this happened here (or any other debugging step), that's probably why people have decided to downvote.

Comment: @Chris Hayes...I have error reporting turned on and there was no relevant notice/warning/error in my log, nor did my console show any Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) error...there was no indicator I could use to debug with, plus I already said the query worked with a comma in my post (first sentence).

Comment: im still not clear on what's going on after all the arguing; the way i read it the actual question has changed 4 times. You can abuse me again but i recommend deleting and asking again, with much greater clarity

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: @Dagon...seriously....4 downvotes for this question? I "abused" you...come on...that's just outrageous. I hope you and the other downvoters have a good day...I really do

Answer (score 1):

You imploded (glued) it again with an underscore, use `,`:

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM login WHERE column IN ('".implode("','", $ExplodedString)."') ORDER BY user";
                                                        //   ^ you glued it with comma not underscore
```

Note: Actually is quite easy to debug this.

Put the query first on a separate variable first, then just use `echo $sql;`. Check up commas, reserved words, etc. so that you know what to expect.

And of course don't forget to turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This is the correct usage on [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: yes, which is not valid in the mysql querry

Comment: OK @Dagon...thank you for the answer...I simply did not know it MUST be a comma, especially since the Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php shows an example implode() with a colon

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob thats about it, Dagon summarized it, why are you imploding it with `_`

Comment: that's the php manual, its the mysql syntax that requires a comma

Comment: Because I needed another delimiter for my table....lots of comma separated strings and for mundane purposes of clarity for me to edit my table I wanted to introduce an underscore delimiter

Comment: no db should have delimited strings, sounds like poor db design

Comment: @Dagon, delimiters work beautifully for me....try to keep an open mind

Comment: @Ghost...my error reporting is already turned on

Comment: says the man posting the question without checking the syntax for his select query.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob what are you saying? you want `('value1'_'value2'_'value3')` instead of `('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`? huh?

Comment: No, the string "String1,String2,String3,String4" is written correctly...String1 is not a variable...I never said it was...String1 is a literal substring of $myString

Comment: @Dagon...my syntax is correct...the query works fine with commas and is 100% correct

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob "Keep an open mind" doesn't apply to bad database design. There are objective measures about this sort of thing. You'll be much happier with your time on SO if you realize there are people here with more experience than you and learn from what they have to say.

Comment: @Chris Hayes...I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad. No delimiter separated strings in my table come from user input, the list size is kept to a maximum value that fits in the table, data type issues are not a problem where I've used delimiters. Rarely do users here ask a question "Why do you do that?"...bashing users with dogma is the theme of SO

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob "bashing users with dogma is the theme of SO" - huh? Trying to encourage best practices is hardly bashing people with dogma. You might find [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) interesting. (There's a great blog post somewhere on the same subject, and how people *really ought* to point out bad design where they see it and save others the headache, but I can't find it anywhere.)

Comment: OK..thanks for a good objective answer, so I'm upvoting your comment